# jquery files conflicting with my php code

Tags: php, jquery

this is my services.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dr Reddy's | Services</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <base href="http://localhost/drreddys/"/>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  .ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;background-color:  cadetblue;}
  .a_heading{width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#ebebeb;}
.a_title{width: 100%;color: #603090;height: 50px;text-align: center;box-shadow: 5px 2px;}
#your-div123 {
    background: url("images/about5.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: border-box;
    height: 400px;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include_once '../admin/header.php';?>
 <div class="a_heading" style="margin-top: 200px;">
       <h1 class="a_title" style="margin-top: 200px;">Services</h1>
     </div>
    <div id="your-div123"></div>
<div id="tabs" style='margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 150px; '>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Primary Care</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Kidney Diseases</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Dialysis Procedures</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-4">Annual Physicals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-5">Adult Immunizations</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#tabs-6">Preventive Health Care</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tabs-7">Pre-operative Clearance</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Primary Care</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Kidney Diseases</h2>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Dialysis Procedures</h2>
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-4" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Annual Physicals</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-5" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Adult Immunizations</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-6" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Preventive Health Care</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-7" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Pre-operative Clearance</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

when i include the jquery files required for tabs functionality, they disturb the page. some part of my homepage gets displayed here.
if i comment the jquery files, the tabs do not function.
please suggest some solution so that i can use tabs as well as the services.php page gets displayed properly.

Comment: i tried to distinguish between jquery-ui and user jquery version. But i did not get the difference

Comment: will changing the versions of jquery files help me?

Comment: can i use jquery.noConflict() function here?